# Storing result of multiplication of two integers in long

Tags: java, type-conversion

I solved a programming question where I had to find the number of 1's in the binary form of the product if 2 numbers A and B. The range of A and B was [0, 10^9] inclusive.
Here is the code I wrote.

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
// System.out.println(solution(32329,4746475));
    System.out.println(solution(3,4));
}

 public static int solution(int A, int B) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8
        long mul=A*B;
        int ans=0;
        while(mul>0)
        {
            if((mul%2)!=0)
            {
                ans++;
            }
            mul=mul/2;
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

This worked fine for the input (3,4) but, when I tried (32329,4746475) as input instead the code didn't work and it showed 0 as answer.
I put in a few output statements at different places to debug and found that with this input, the result of multiplication comes out to be -1170032381 (which is wrong) and therefore, the while loop's condition fails. So, I type-casted both A and B like so

```
long mul=(long)A*(long)B;
```

And voila it worked. Now, my question is why?
Why did the code work fine for smaller inputs and flop for larger ones and shouldn't 'int to long' be implicit type casting in Java?

(I also tried a few other inputs so not all larger ones give negative as the product but they don't give the correct answer either, smaller ones I've tried till 5-digit A and B give the correct product)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java has automatic widening from `int` to `long`, but that happens at *assignment*, but the multiplication of an `int` with another `int` produces an `int`, so you would get [integer overflow](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) *first* multiplying `32329` with `4746475`, *then* the widening of the overflowed `int` result to `long`.

However, if you *first* cast at least one of the `int` to `long`, then the multiplication is done using `long` and the result is `long`, so no integer overflow.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It clarified my doubt. I don't have the rep to upvote it though.

Answer (score 0):

Java int can store from

```
-2147483648 to 2147483647

32329 X 4746475 =153448790275
```

as Java does the multiplication before the implicit conversion the result is wrong

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I don't have the rep to upvote it but it helped nonetheless.